# Unsure about the time complexity

Tags: c++, time, time-complexity, divide-and-conquer

So I was doing a question on LeetCode...
Question:

```
Write an efficient algorithm that searches for a target value in an m x n integer matrix. The matrix has the following properties:

Integers in each row are sorted in ascending from left to right.
Integers in each column are sorted in ascending from top to bottom.
 
Example 1:
Input: matrix = [[1,4,7,11,15],[2,5,8,12,19],[3,6,9,16,22],[10,13,14,17,24],[18,21,23,26,30]], target = 5
Output: true

Example 2:
Input: matrix = [[1,4,7,11,15],[2,5,8,12,19],[3,6,9,16,22],[10,13,14,17,24],[18,21,23,26,30]], target = 20
Output: false
```

So first I attempted this question by regular brute force method:
Answer-1:

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool searchMatrix(vector<vector<int>>& matrix, int t) {
        int i=0,j,I=matrix.size(),J,mj;
        for(;i<I;i++)
        {
            j=0;J=matrix[i].size()-1;
            mj=(j+J)/2;
            while(j<=J)
            {
                if(matrix[i][mj]==t)
                    return true;
                else if(matrix[i][mj]<t)
                    j=mj+1;
                else
                    J=mj-1;
                mj=(j+J)/2;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Then I decided to do it by idk Divide and Conquer ig...
Answer-2:

```
class Solution {
public:
    
    bool VFinder(vector<vector<int>>& matrix, int hstart, int hend, int vstart, int vend, int ele)
    {
        if(vstart > vend || hstart > hend)
            return false;
        
        int mid = vstart;
        int start = vstart;
        int end = vend;
        while(start<=end)
        {
            mid = (int)((start + end) / 2);
            if (start == end)
         {
            if (matrix[mid][hstart] == ele)
            {
               return true;
            }
            else
            {
               return HFinder(matrix, hstart + 1, hend, vstart, mid, ele);
            }
         }
            else
            {if(matrix[mid][hstart] <ele && matrix[mid+1][hstart] > ele)
                return HFinder(matrix, hstart+1, hend, vstart, mid,ele);
            else if(matrix[mid][hstart] <ele)
                start = mid+1;
            else if(matrix[mid][hstart] >ele)
                end = mid-1;
            else if(matrix[mid][hstart] == ele)
                return true;}
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    bool HFinder(vector<vector<int>>& matrix, int hstart, int hend, int vstart, int vend, int ele)
    {
        if(hstart > hend || vstart > vend)
            return false;
        
        int mid = hstart;
        int start = hstart;
        int end = hend;
        while(start<=end)
        {
            mid = (int)((start + end) / 2);
            if (start == end)
         {
            if (matrix[vstart][mid] == ele)
            {
               return true;
            }
            else
            {
               return VFinder(matrix, hstart, mid, vstart + 1, vend, ele);
            }
         }
            else
            {if(matrix[vstart][mid] <ele && matrix[vstart][mid+1] > ele)
                return VFinder(matrix, hstart, mid, vstart+1, vend, ele);
            else if(matrix[vstart][mid] <ele)
                start = mid+1;
            else if(matrix[vstart][mid] >ele)
                end = mid-1;
            else if(matrix[vstart][mid] == ele)
                return true;}
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    bool searchMatrix(vector<vector<int>>& matrix, int target) {
        int horizontal = matrix[0].size();
        int vertical = matrix.size();
        return HFinder(matrix, 0, horizontal-1, 0, vertical-1, target);
    }
};
```

So the first code after submission took about : `328 ms`
And the second one took about : `488 ms`

But in second one, I am after each step reducing the search space, so it should have taken less time as compared to the first code, but it is not happening so.
Can someone please tell me why is it so?
And also what is the time complexity of the second code?

Comment: Note that this problem has an easy linear solution. Start from the top right corner. If the element there is greater than the target, move one left; if it's less, move one down. Repeat until target is found or you walk off the left or bottom edge. Makes at most `2*n` comparisons. (Equivalently, start from bottom left corner and move up or right).

Comment: I don't think your second solution is actually reducing the search space as fast as you think it is.  I suggest stepping through it and noting the calls.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I already tried this too but in one of the test case it showed time limit exceeded.

Comment: You must have done something wrong. There's no solution faster than linear here.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I inserted the code in the question you can check there if there is some mistake or not... If there is, then please notify me regarding that..

Comment: top right corner, that is `i=0, j=J` and you would be moving `i++` and `j--`

Comment: That doesn't at all resemble the solution I propose. It starts checking from the top left corner `[0][0]`, not the top right corner `[0][n-1]`. And it's quadratic on the face of it, with two nested loops; whereas mine is linear, requiring only one loop.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Ok yeah I see I didn't realize that...

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That definitely worked ty for that, but I wanted to practice on some divide and conquer questions so can you tell me how can I apply that on this question, and also is the second method which I applied will be considered divide and conquer or not?

Comment: @LorenPechtel Ig you are right, can you tell me whether the second method which I applied will be considered divide and conquer or not? And if not then how can I apply D/C in this question it would really be helpful

Comment: I must admit I don't understand what you are doing in that second method. Too convoluted for me.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Well, the second one really is hectic, I admit that T_T Can you then just tell me how can I apply the D/C in this question it would really be helpful...

Comment: The second method seems to be confused about what it's doing which makes it hard to analyze. By the fact it only ever advances hstart to hstart+1 and vstart to vstart+1 I would guess it has to search a rectangular area and it is quadratic or worse.

Comment: @dratenik Well it also reduces vend to mid and hend to mid...

Comment: but it always accesses *start in one dimension, so unless you bring start to the right place, it won't find anything

Comment: You want divide and conquer? Split the matrix into four quarters, you should only have to recursively search one of them.

Comment: @dratenik Checking an element in the center only lets you eliminate one quarter (top left or bottom right), not three. Leaving you with three quarters to search.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I was thinking of checking the corners of each of the quarters. But I have not given it all that much thought.

Comment: @dratenik I don't believe that would let you eliminate more than one quarter in general; the same one that would be eliminated by checking just the center.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik imagining an example with a diagonal with numbers close to the goal - yeah, you're right; and you have to check all those numbers, so the best this can hope for is replicating what the linear algorithm does (with extra steps...)

Comment: @dratenik gives a good hint. I am writing up a post that describes the proper approach and will post later today.  In a nutshell -- the search ***can*** be done faster than linear with a two-dimensional binary-like search.